# Get sum of different column of different table in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, group-by

I am getting wrong sum answer by this query - does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? I am getting the first sum twice, the second sum 3 times more than the actual value and so on.

```
SELECT ogr.Region_ID,
       ogr.Region_Name,
       Sum(daf.Total_Allowance) AS DailyAllowance,
       Sum(naf.Total_Allowance) AS NightAllowance,
       Sum(caf.Total_Amount) AS AdvanceCash,
       Sum(att.Extra_Amounts) AS OverTime,
       Sum(eef.Total_Amount) AS EmployeeExpense,
       Sum(maf.Total_Amount) AS MobileAllowance,
       Sum(odf.On_Week_Amount) AS OnWeek,
       Sum(emp.Salary) AS EmployeeSalary
FROM   ORG_Region ogr
       LEFT OUTER JOIN DailyAllowanceForm AS daf
                    ON daf.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN NightAllowance AS naf
                    ON naf.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN CashAdvance AS caf
                    ON caf.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Attandence AS att
                    ON att.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN EmployeeExpensesForm AS eef
                    ON eef.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN MobileAllowance AS maf
                    ON maf.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN OnDutyForms AS odf
                    ON odf.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee AS emp
                    ON emp.Region = ogr.Region_ID
GROUP  BY ogr.Region_ID,ogr.Region_Name
```

Comment: Why don't you use `inner join` here? Also do you use _enable_, _disable_ flags in these tables?

Comment: Could you show sample data and sample results?

Comment: if naf has 3 rows no matter for which region then it will sum all three and display the sum in front of that region. it is due to left outer join

Answer (score 2):

The clean solution is using CTE, cook aggregate values then join it:

```
;WITH daf as (
   SELECT Region_ID, SUM(Total_Allowance) as DailyAllowance 
   FROM DailyAllowanceForm GROUP BY Region_ID
), naf as (
   SELECT Region_ID, SUM(Total_Allowance) as NightAllowance 
   FROM NightAllowance GROUP BY Region_ID
), caf as (
  ...
) 
SELECT ogr.Region_ID, ogr.Region_Name, 
       coalesce(daf.DailyAllowance, 0) AS DailyAllowance,
       coalesce(naf.NightAllowance, 0) AS NightAllowance,
       ...
FROM
   ORG_Region ogr 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   daf               ON daf.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN  
   naf               ON naf.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
   ...
GROUP BY ogr.Region_ID,ogr.Region_Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT ogr.Region_ID, ogr.Region_Name, ISNULL(daf.DailyAllowance, 0) AS DailyAllowance, ISNULL(naf.NightAllowance, 0) AS NightAllowance, 
       ISNULL(caf.AdvanceCash, 0) AS AdvanceCash, ISNULL(att.OverTime, 0) AS OverTime, ISNULL(eef.EmployeeExpense, 0) AS EmployeeExpense, 
       ISNULL(maf.MobileAllowance, 0) AS MobileAllowance, ISNULL(odf.OnWeek, 0) AS OnWeek, ISNULL(emp.EmployeeSalary, 0) AS EmployeeSalary
FROM   ORG_Region ogr
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Region_ID, SUM(Total_Allowance) DailyAllowance FROM DailyAllowanceForm GROUP BY Region_ID) AS daf ON daf.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Region_ID, SUM(Total_Allowance) NightAllowance FROM NightAllowance GROUP BY Region_ID) AS naf ON naf.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Region_ID, SUM(Total_Amount) AS AdvanceCash FROM CashAdvance GROUP BY Region_ID) AS caf ON caf.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Region_ID, SUM(Extra_Amounts) AS OverTime FROM Attandence GROUP BY Region_ID) AS att ON att.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Region_ID, SUM(Total_Amount) AS EmployeeExpense FROM EmployeeExpensesForm GROUP BY Region_ID) AS eef ON eef.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Region_ID, SUM(Total_Amount) AS MobileAllowance FROM MobileAllowance GROUP BY Region_ID) AS maf ON maf.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Region_ID, SUM(On_Week_Amount) AS OnWeek FROM OnDutyForms GROUP BY Region_ID) AS odf ON odf.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Region_ID, SUM(Salary) AS EmployeeSalary FROM Employee GROUP BY Region_ID) AS emp ON emp.Region = ogr.Region_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT ogr.Region_ID,
       ogr.Region_Name,
       Sum(daf.Total_Allowance) AS DailyAllowance,
       Sum(naf.Total_Allowance) AS NightAllowance,
       Sum(caf.Total_Amount) AS AdvanceCash,
       Sum(att.Extra_Amounts) AS OverTime,
       Sum(eef.Total_Amount) AS EmployeeExpense,
       Sum(maf.Total_Amount) AS MobileAllowance,
       Sum(odf.On_Week_Amount) AS OnWeek,
       Sum(emp.Salary) AS EmployeeSalary
FROM   ORG_Region ogr
       INNER JOIN DailyAllowanceForm AS daf
                ON daf.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
       INNER JOIN NightAllowance AS naf
                ON naf.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
       INNER JOIN CashAdvance AS caf
                ON caf.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
       INNER JOIN Attandence AS att
                ON att.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
       INNER JOIN EmployeeExpensesForm AS eef
                ON eef.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
       INNER JOIN MobileAllowance AS maf
                ON maf.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
       INNER JOIN OnDutyForms AS odf
                ON odf.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
       INNER JOIN Employee AS emp
                ON emp.Region = ogr.Region_ID
   GROUP  BY ogr.Region_ID,ogr.Region_Name
```

Another Way is

```
SELECT  ogr.Region_ID ,
    ogr.Region_Name ,
    ( SELECT    ISNULL(( SUM(daf.Total_Allowance) ), 0)
      FROM      DailyAllowanceForm AS daf
      WHERE     daf.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
    ) AS DailyAllowance ,
    ( SELECT    ISNULL(( SUM(naf.Total_Allowance) ), 0)
      FROM      NightAllowance AS naf
      WHERE     naf.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
    ) AS NightAllowance ,
    ( SELECT    ISNULL(( SUM(caf.Total_Amount) ), 0)
      FROM      CashAdvance AS caf
      WHERE     caf.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
    ) AS AdvanceCash ,
    ( SELECT    ISNULL(( SUM(att.Extra_Amounts) ), 0)
      FROM      Attandence AS att
      WHERE     att.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
    ) AS OverTime ,
    ( SELECT    ISNULL(( SUM(eef.Total_Amount) ), 0)
      FROM      EmployeeExpensesForm AS eef
      WHERE     eef.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
    ) AS EmployeeExpense ,
    ( SELECT    ISNULL(( SUM(maf.Total_Amount) ), 0)
      FROM      MobileAllowance AS maf
      WHERE     maf.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
    ) AS MobileAllowance ,
    ( SELECT    ISNULL(( SUM(odf.On_Week_Amount) ), 0)
      FROM      OnDutyForms AS odf
      WHERE     odf.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
    ) AS OnWeek ,
    ( SELECT    ISNULL(( SUM(emp.Salary) ), 0)
      FROM      Employee AS emp
      WHERE     emp.Region_ID = ogr.Region_ID
    ) AS EmployeeSalary
 FROM    ORG_Region ogr
 GROUP BY ogr.Region_ID ,
 ogr.Region_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are adding from duplicated rows:

TableA

```
Aid, Avalue
1, 7
2, 3
```

TableB

```
Aid
1
1
2
2
2
```

you ill get sums like 14 and 9
since you are counting B multiple times.

split that big select in sub queries like in Prashant answer